# Where does Office 2016 for Mac download updates?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office

A fresh install of Office 2016 for Mac requires gigabytes of updates. Where abouts on the file system does it download the updates prior to installing them?

Ideally I'd like to grab them before they're installed, so I can install them on other machines without having to download them every time.

Comment: A downvote? Feel free to comment on why you think this isn't appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft AutoUpdate's temporary download location is

```
/private/var/folders/hh/41_uid/T/CFNetworkDownload_uid.tmp
```

Once the download has been completed, the package is placed in

```
/private/var/folders/hh/41_uid/T/MSau_uid/Microsoft_appname_version_Updater.pkg
```

For example, `/private/var/folders/hh/41_x4gjd5sl_fmdsmglz94xw0000gn/T/MSau_38352/Microsoft_PowerPoint_15.30.16121500_Updater.pkg`

These packages are deleted once installed.

You can keep your Office products open so that once an update is downloaded from MAU, it will pause and tell you to close your apps. That way you'll have time to copy the update package to a new location before it gets installed and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need them all.

Even if you start with an old installer, all you need is the Service Pack 1 update, then the latest [currently 14.7.1]

Service Pack 1 is at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17198

14.7.1 is at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54504

If you really want to scrabble around looking for them, one at a time as the auto updater fetches them, they live in `~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/`

Comment: aaaand... I just realised all my info is for Office 2011. I'll leave it here for now, in case the locations are similar.

Comment: Yeah this information is quite outdated, I don't even have a TemporaryItems folder!